# Custom UITextField created programmatically doesnt bring up keyboard on tap

Tags: ios, uitextfield, custom-view, uitextfielddelegate

I have a custom look designed for my textfields on iphone. I decided to create a class

`MYTextField : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate>`

I have a method

```
- (id)initWithPlaceholder:(NSString*)placeholder position:(CGPoint) position
```

that creates a UITextField with the desired view and look.

The sourcecode is as follows:

```
- (id)initWithPlaceholder:(NSString*)placeholder position:(CGPoint) position {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(position.x, position.y, TEXTFIELD_WIDTH, TEXTFIELD_HEIGHT)]) {
        UITextField *textField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40)] autorelease];
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        textField.placeholder = @"enter text";
        textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;    
        [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        textField.delegate = self;

        [self addSubview:textField];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The problem is that, on invoking the method, the UITextField is visible but on tapping on the textfield, the keyboard doesnt show up.

Is there anything I am missing?

PS: I found a couple of similar problems on Stackoverflow, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here could be that the textfields frame doesn't lie within the frame of the UIView. Why use TEXTFIELD_WIDTH for the self.frame but not for textfield.frame?

Also, why subclass UIView rather that UITextField?

Comment: I am planning to add UIImageView and probably customize it a bit more. Hence I subclassed UIView instead of UITextField

Comment: Thanks! silly me.. :) +1 for the right answer. I was assigning the same width and height for both the textfield and view that contained it.